# Number theory problem try

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Here is a nice number theory problem:

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. Determine all divisors $d \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ of $3n^2$ which are such that the number $n^2 + d$ is equal to a perfect square of an Integer.

Here is what we've done so far:
$d \mid 3n^2 \implies 1 \leq d  \leq 3n^2 \land \exists m \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that $3n^2 = dm$.
Now notice $n^2 + d = k^2$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. $n^2+d=k^2 \iff d = k^2 - n^2 \iff d=(k-n)(k+n)$.

Now we are at a point where we need to reach the next step. What should that step be?

Comment: Well, you must at least have searched for example, right?  What did you find?

Comment: $d$ can be written as $d=ab$ or $d=3ab,$ where $a\mid b\mid n$ Not aure if that helps.

Comment: Are we searching for all such pairs $(d,n)$? Then start with $n=1$. This gives only $d=3$. What do you get for $n=2$?

Comment: FWIW, $d=3n^2$ obviously always works

Comment: There's certainly at least one solution, $d=3n^2.$ You have $n<k\leq 2n.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably an easier argument exists, but this seems to work.

Since $n<k^2\leq 4n^2,$ you have $n< k\leq 2n.$ So let $m=k-n.$

Then $d=(k-n)(k+n)=m(m+2n).$

If $p^j\mid d,$ for $p\neq 2,3$ prime, then $p^{j}\mid n^2.$ Then $p^{\lceil j/2\rceil}\mid n.$ So for $2i\leq j+1,$ $p^i\mid m\iff p^i\mid m+2n.$

So $\nu_p(d)=\nu_p(m)+\nu_p(m+2n)=2\nu_p(m).$

This means $d$ must be of one of the forms $e^2,3e^2,$ where $e\mid n,$ or $2e^2,6e^2$ where $2e\mid n.$

Case $2e\mid n:$ Write $n=2en_0.$ Then if $d= 2e^2,$ then $n^2+d=e^2(4n_0^2+2)$ which is never a square. Same for $d=6e^2.$

Case $e\mid n:$ Write $n=en_0.$ Then $n^2+d=e^2(n_0^2+1)$ or $n^2+d=e^2(n_0^2+3).$ The is only a square if $d=3e^2$ and $n_0=1,$ so $n=e, d=3n^2.$

So $d=3n^2$ is the only solution for any $n>0.$

---

This seems to generalize to other primes. If $d\mid 7n^2,$ then $n^2+d$ js a perfect square if and only if $3\mid n$ and $d=7\left(\frac{n}{3}\right)^2.$

If $d\mid pn^2$ for $p$ an odd prime, then $n^2+d$ is a square iff $\frac{p-1}2\mid n$ and $d=p\left(\frac{2n}{p-1}\right)^2.$